# Cube faces get overwritten by hidden surfaces

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

In the OpenGL SuperBible on page 124 is an example of a rotating cube.

I implemented the code close to what the book stated and the sides of my cube are partially transperent. I have problems identifying why i can see through certain parts of the cube. I written the cube data myself so there may be an issue with that.

- I double checked my cube vertices.
- I tried disabling culling using
  `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` in my render function.
- I tried setting the
  alpha channel to a fixed value in my shader.

I am out of ideas why my cube could be partially transparent.
Render function:

```
void Chapter5_Page124::render(double currentTime)
{
    GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    float f = (float)(currentTime * M_PI * 0.1);
    vmath::mat4 mv_matrix =
        vmath::translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f) *
        vmath::translate
        (
        sinf(2.1f * f) * 0.5f,
        cosf(1.7f * f) * 0.5f,
        sinf(1.3f * f) * 0.5f * cosf(1.5f * f) * 2.0f
        ) *
        vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) *
        vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 81.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
    glUseProgram(*program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 430 core                                                 
in vec4 position;
out VS_OUT
{
    vec4 color;
}vs_out;
uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
void main(void)                                                   
{                                                                 
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;
    vs_out.color = position * 2 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    vs_out.color.a = 1;
}
```

A screen shots of the cube in different rotations:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What went wrong with my cube? How can i fix it?

---

EDIT 4

Removed non relevant information from the question.
Changed the Question since i now understand better what is happening.

Comment: I think you need to enable [GL_DEPTH_TEST](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Test)

Comment: @gre_gor ah, retried it with different conditions. works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the error was in the render function.
It took me a while to realize it.

```
void Chapter5_Page124::render(double currentTime)
{
    GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    float f = (float)(currentTime * M_PI * 0.1);

    vmath::mat4 mv_matrix =
        vmath::translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f) *
        vmath::translate
        (
        sinf(2.1f * f) * 0.5f,
        cosf(1.7f * f) * 0.5f,
        sinf(1.3f * f) * 0.5f * cosf(1.5f * f) * 2.0f
        ) *
        vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) *
        vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 81.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
    glUseProgram(*program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}
```

---

Edit:

This answer does not quite nail it, but i found another resource that gives better insight of why this is happening and how to fix it.
[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/NS980twY1ZE?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh&t=812)